# How to specify different heights for browsers in different OS's

Tags: css, browser

I'm trying to get a border to display to a certain point on a page. I need to to align with the bottom of some content. However, in FF on the Mac I can do so just fine, but any other browser (Windows or Mac) it will not display to the desired length.

I try to write in to the CSS -webkit and -moz declarations of height under the same selector, but they never take any effect.

```
    -moz-height: 1100px !important;
    -webkit-height:1067px !important;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Can you share some more of your code? There might be something else you can tweak to make the content the same across all the browsers.

Comment: the background-repeat: repeat-y; doesn't even work...not even with !important

Comment: sure Jrod:

the css is #leftBorderRight {
    height: 1077px !important;
    -moz-height: 1100px !important;
    -webkit-height:1067px !important;
}

Comment: not exactly what I meant. Likely there is some other element that is causing them not to line up. It could be a variety of things such as padding, margin, different font sizes or box-sizing that could account for the difference across browsers. If you can provide a link to your full project or a fiddle with your html and css that would help.

Comment: yeah it'd be highly frowned upon if I posted code in the entirety..looks like I'll just have to figure this one out myself. I don't understand why background-repeat: repeat-y; doesn't work though..

There are these templates that I have to work with though that there is TONS of inline CSS and sometimes 5 classes on one element, and the section to that CSS is often stuff that I don't have access to do, and since inline often can't over-ride with CSS declarations in the page.

Comment: Sorry Jay without seeing a link to your site it is really difficult to help you with your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Height doesn't have browser prefixes.

generally only specific experimental, or CSS being considered from the spec have browser specific prefixes

Comment: so what you are saying is that I cannot set a height for certain browsers to be different?

Comment: I agree with Robert. Height is a standard property long ago and does not have browser prefixes. Please provide more code, maybe there is another option to help you out.